# Модульное тестирование REST сервиса

Tags: java, rest, юнит-тесты, junit, тестирование

Пишу REST сервис на CDI. Используется библиотека [helidon](https://helidon.io/). При запуске этот сервис получает часть конфигурации с другого сервиса. Это сделано при помощи специального config-интерфейса `org.eclipse.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigSource`. Класс, реализующий этот интерфейс загружается через ServiceLoader, в конструкторе делает запрос к удаленному REST-сервису, получает с него конфигурацию и потом ее отдает тому кто попросит.

Теперь мне для моего сервиса нужно написать модульные тесты. Проблема в том, что тестирующий движок запускает сервис в самом начале, до возникновения всяких `@BeforeAll`, когда можно было бы настроить, например Mockito и переопределить работу этого класса. Сервис ломится на удаленный сервис, его не находит и на этом все завершается с исключением.

Вопрос. Как решить данную проблему? Меня устроит даже вариант, если в фазе тестирования ServiceLoader просто не будет создавать экземпляр этого конфигурационного класса.

Comment: 1. Переделать полностью архитектуру.
2. Создать моковый веб сервер.

Comment: @Tsyklop какие рекомендации по архитектуре? Что гуглить по моковому веб-серверу? И когда его запускать если тестируемый сервис стартует до BeforeAll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было найдено. Я определил класс с тем же именем, который реализовывал интерфейс `ConfigSource` но в папке test/java. В итоге ServiceLoader стал загружать именно тестовую реализацию